# SelfSLL, Microsoft Management Console, Certificate Not Displaying

Tags: windows-8, ssl, certificate, mmc

I am currently attempting to create a self-signed certificate with the `SelfSSL.exe` tool from Microsoft's [IIS 6.0 Resource Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17275) (I have the metabase compatability enabled); however, when creating the certificate - though not prompted with an error - I am unable to see the newly created certificate in the Microsoft Management Console, despite [following the instructions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632629.aspx) provided by Microsoft's TechNet.

I have Administrative rights on my computer. Is there a step I am missing?

I enter the command as instructed (see image):

`SELFSSL /N:cn=*.HIDDEN.local /V:3650 /S:3 /K:2048`

[image: Console after create]

I then type `Y` and press `ENTER`.

Here is the prompt, post `Y` (e.g. nothing):

[image]

I have reproduced my steps above, exactly, yet cannot see the certificate. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run the command console in Admin. mode ("Run as Administrator"), if you are not already. This Administrator mode is much more explicit and will log errors not accessible to non-Admin. modes. This also appears to be necessary for the creation of certificates.

A successful create operation should prompt you with a success message.